# How to return message "Please enter a valid number" in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm running a brief javascript code (ECMAScript 5.1) for a query in an API and I had a question:

When I run on the API: https://api.url.com/api/punch/workData?externalId={{employeeId}}

I save the results on the variable: "response" and use the code:

```
function run(response) {
    var balance = JSON.parse(response)[0].hoursBalance;
    return Math.round(balance/3600)
    }
```

I got the expected result:

```
response: [{"employeeId": 2137764, "employerId": 2147830, "plannedWorkingDay": 158400.0, "fulfilledWorkingDay": 113940.0, "hoursBalance": 44460.0}
balance: -12
```

However I need to return an error message to the user when the "response" is blank. Got this result when the employeeId is invalid.

```
response: []
```

How can I do this?

Thanks!
Luis

Comment: It bothers me that `externalId` is not actually an ID but an array of user objects serialised into JSON,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "throw" to create a error
for example

```
if (!externalId) throw "not good"
```

For more information about this checkout https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp
Additionally use a try catch block to catch any error in javascript as

```
try{
    //something that has thrown a error
} catch (err) {
    //alert the user to do something different
   //possibly alert("error: " + err.message);
}
```

With try catch blocks your code will continue to run as if the error has been handled, which will allow the user to re-enter their details.

Comment: `externalId` is a string and it's non-empty when OP receives it, so this check doesn't filter all invalid input.

Comment: Just curious did you write the api function as well?

Comment: In fact I expressed myself badly. Sorry!
externalId is my variable which I use to query in the API
I changed the name of the externalId variable to "Response"

I edited the original post for a better understanding

Comment: @Mick no, just use one.

Comment: If you want trap a error in js use the "try" "catch" block and then show a message to the user

Comment: Ty @Mick Like that?

`function run(response) {
    try {
        var balance = JSON.parse(response)[0].hoursBalance;
        return Math.round(balance/3600) }
    catch(err) {
        "Invalid employee Id number. Try again"
}
    }`


But how i´m print this message to user?

Comment: use the alert("Invalid employee Id number. Try again");

Comment: got: error: "ReferenceError: alert is not defined"
I´m think because is (ECMAScript 5.1)

Comment: alert should work. its been around for ever and a day.

Comment: Problem solveld. Ty @Mick `function run(response) {
    try {
        var balance = JSON.parse(response)[0].hoursBalance;
        return Math.round(balance/3600) }
    catch(err) {
        return "Invalid number, try again."
}
    }`